# How to assign variable as class in Flash Builder 4 Hero SDK

Tags: apache-flex, flash, flexbuilder, builder, navigator

I am trying to assign a variable to a view navigation as follows:

```
protected function list_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var name1:String = list.selectedItem.vPage;
            var name2:Object = list.selectedItem.vPage.valueOf();               

            navigator.pushView(list.selectedItem.vPage.valueOf(), list.selectedItem);
        }
```

The variable is supposed to be the view for instance it works fine as follows:

```
navigator.pushView(IM, list.selectedItem);
```

As the View is presented as a static and not a variable. When you try to submit it as a variable in any format (String, Object) an error occurs.

```
Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: cannot convert "IM" to Class.
```

So if anyone has any ideas on how I can send the (View)Class as a variable or if this is a bug in the SDK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not a bug in the SDK.  You pass in a class, and the `viewNavigator` will construct it for you.  If you want to get the the `Class` of an instance of an object, you can do it like this:

```
var viewClass = Class(getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName(IM)));
```

Then, you can pass `viewClass` into `pushView()` where it will create a NEW view for you.

Comment: Many thanks for this response. This had been puzzling for a few hours.